# Count all person booked on the same date, for the next 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have setup a booking system for a day tour which collects the number of booked people - adults & children and of course the date for the tour. The maximum total number of people on the tour is limited to 40.

In my "booking" table I have "ID", "tourDate", "erwachs" (adults), "kinder"(children) and a lot more data stored.

What I have now is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM buchung
        where tourDatum >= curdate()
                and tourDatum <= curdate() + INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY tourDatum";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"tourDatum");
$adult=mysql_result($result,$i,"erwachs");
$children=mysql_result($result,$i,"kinder");
$free=(40 - ($adult+$children));
echo "Tour Date - Spaces<br/>$first - $free <br/>";
$i++;}
```

But this is not collecting all booked spaces

---

Hi and thankks for your answer. Unfortunately that did don't work for me. The above code did not work. I have now used the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM buchung
where tourDate >= curdate()
and tourDate <= curdate() + INTERVAL 7 DAY GROUP BY tourDate";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"tourDATE");
$adult=mysql_result($result,$i,"adults");
$children=mysql_result($result,$i,"children");
free=(40 - ($adult+$children));
echo "Tour Date - Spaces<br/>$first - $free <br/>";
$i++;}
```

but this did NOT summarize all the people booked for that day. Any idea how to summarize all numbers between the given dates, grouped by day.

**To explain:**
Lets say on *25.03.2014*

- one booking: 2 adults and 1 child
- one booking: 4 Adults and 2 Children

**So the result should be:**

6 Adults + 3 Children = 9 Person.

Then of course they should be deducted from the mximum number of 40 person, and ther displayed result should be 31 for that day.

Comment: Please post more information, including relevant schema details, what you've attempted so far, and how your actual results are differing from your expected results. As it stands, you have not provided enough information to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    date_format(tourDate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS 'tour date',
    (40 - (count(adults) + count(children))) AS 'free spaces'
FROM booking
where date_format(tourDate,'%Y-%m-%d') >= curdate()
    and date_format(tourDate,'%Y%m%d') <= curdate() + INTERVAL 7 DAY 
GROUP BY date_format(tourDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
```